# How-to get a menu label via $post-> or $page->ID

Tags: wordpress

*Entirely Revised Please Reread*

Hello,
The theme I am using displays the page's title as opposed to it's menu label in the breadcrumbs. I am trying to get the breadcrumbs to instead display the associated menu label if it is available and if not then default to the page_title.

I have come up with some code that I think is close. Line 4/// $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $slug ); returns null and it should return the nav item that contains $slug of the current post. Obviously, there is something I do not understand.

What I am attempting to do is get the slug of the current post, then using the slug get the nav item post. Then extract the title of the nav item and use that in place of the page title in the breadcrumbs. If the page was not in the nav system then it should default to the page title, as might be the case for a ppc campaign landing page.

```
if ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
    $title = null;
    $slug = mpactMEDIA_get_the_slug( get_the_ID() );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $slug );
    //var_dump((array)$menu_items);
    foreach ( (array)$menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $title = $menu_item->post_title;
    }
    if ( $title ) { echo $delimiter . ' ' . $before . $title . $after; }
    else { echo $delimiter . ' ' . $before . get_the_title() . $after; }
}
```

I'm my functions.php file I have the following function

```
function mpactMEDIA_get_the_slug( $id=null ){
    if( empty($id) ) global $post;
    if( empty($post) ) return '';
        $id = $post->ID;
    endif;
    $slug = basename( get_permalink($id) );
    return $slug;
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Tim

Comment: Can you reduce this giant function to only the part you're interested?

Comment: Not a problem Brasfilo. I've edited the post and tried to clarify my query a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the question a few times, I got here searching for an answer, ended up making my own.

```
function get_menu_label_by_post_id($post_id, $menu) {

    $menu_title = '';
    $nav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu);

    foreach ( $nav as $item ) {

        if ( $post_id == $item->object_id ) {
            $menu_title = $item->post_title;
            break;
        }

    }

    return ($menu_title !== '') ? $menu_title : get_the_title($post_id);

}
```

Example usage:

```
echo get_menu_label_by_post_id($post->ID, 'Primary Nav');
```

This will return what the menu label is if it finds it, otherwise just the title of the post ID.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) for `wp_get_nav_menu_items`. It doesn't take a page slug as a parameter at all.

If you want to list child pages of a given page, use [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) and pass a `child_of` parameter to it.

Also, as a side note, if you know the `$post` and want the slug, it's just `$post->post_name`

Comment: So the slug for the menu isn't the same as the page? How are the nav items linked to the pages? I decided to grab the post_name because it allows me to retrieve the slug of any page regardless of whether or not it is the current post, such as the slug of the parent of the current post.

Comment: @mpactMEDIA wp_get_nav_menu_items uses the menu ID, check the documentation. Menu item may or may not be linking to pages. When they are I *think* the info is carried as an extra property (like object_id) or something like this, do some var_dump if you need.

Comment: Wouldn't be just easier to rename the original page title if you're going to replace it everywhere with the menu name anyway?

Comment: No, it's a semantic and SEO thing. This particular theme by default is using the page title as the token in the breadcrumb. Which is not how it is listed in the nav menu. Thus the "Our Services" page may have a nine word title on the page itself. The breadcrumbs should be the same as the menu labels. It makes it easier for a prospect to know what they clicked on in the nav menu because it is sitting there in the breadcrumbs. more........

Comment: ...continued. Also, we will be creating some landing pages for a PPC campaign that will not be linked in the nav menus and for those the page title should show up in the breadcrumbs as it will be their search term they used to find the site.